# Modify pop up iframe google calendar

Tags: python, django, google-calendar-api

I have an iframe on my web page to display google calendar. I am using django and it correctly shows me the events that I create.
I've been looking for several days, but I can't find a way to modify the pop up that the iframe generates when you select an event.

Let's see if someone can give me some ideas on how to do it or where to look.

A greeting.

This is my code iframe generate for Google:

```
<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?height=700&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23ffffff&amp;ctz=Europe%2FMadrid&amp;src=amZhbHZhcmV6MjMyQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ&amp;color=%23039BE5&amp;title=Web%20Asociacion&amp;showDate=1&amp;showPrint=0&amp;showTabs=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;showTz=0" style="border:solid 1px #777" width="900" height="700" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: May I suggest that you add some of the code you used to help others investigate a [Re-Producible problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please read over [Runnable Code Issues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Due to the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) policy, you can't

If you have an iframe on your website, unless that iframe is generated from the *same origin* then you won't have access to it.

If it does come from the same origin, you can do something like the following:

```js
document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.document
```

Though since you are using Google Calendar as an iframe, you won't have access to it as it's origin is Google's servers.